# How do i get specific records with sql?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a page where the records from the database are displayed on the site. If there are more then 25 records I wanna make it so you have multiple pages, I need a query to do this.

For example if my query is the following:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "A%"`

I'll get 70 names that are starting with an A, what query do I need if I only want to get the 26th till 50th name?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im using PHPMyAdmin